# Android checkbox is checked not working

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

so i have this Activity and i have 2 checkboxes , when the user clicks one of them it will be checked and toast a text "11111" and "222222" also when the user joins the activity they will get the toast "Welcome". Now , the Welcome toast is working but the if.s doesent seem to work. What could be the problem?

Here is my code

```
package com.myapp.pack;

import com.myapp.pack.R;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class settup extends Activity {
     private String SENDER_ID = "xxx";
     private String PUSHBOT_ID = "xxx";
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "BuyMeCheckBoxes";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notifsettings);
        Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID , PUSHBOT_ID);
        Pushbots.getInstance().setMsgReceiver(GoToApp.class);
        Pushbots.getInstance().setRegStatus(true);
        Toast.makeText(settup.this, 
                "A-ti accesat setarile app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          CheckBox auto = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
          CheckBox imobiliare = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);


        if (auto.isChecked()) {
            auto.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(settup.this, 
                    "1111111", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

        if (imobiliare.isChecked()) {
            auto.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(settup.this, 
                    "2222222", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }






      // Array of choices
    //      String colors[] = {"Toata Tara","Oradea","Timisoara","Bucuresti","Cluj-Napoca","Constanta","Iasi","Suceava","Targu Mures"};

        // Selection of the spinner


        // Application of the Array to the Spinner
    //      ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
    //      spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
    //      spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);




    }


    protected void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        final CheckBox auto = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         final CheckBox imobiliare = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);



          SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

         boolean c1 = settings.getBoolean("auto", false);
        boolean c2 = settings.getBoolean("imobiliare", false);

        auto.setChecked(c1);
        imobiliare.setChecked(c2);

    } 


    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
       final CheckBox auto = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
       final CheckBox imobiliare = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

      boolean checkBoxValue1 = auto.isChecked();
      boolean checkBoxValue2 = imobiliare.isChecked();  

      editor.putBoolean("auto", checkBoxValue1);
      editor.putBoolean("imobiliare", checkBoxValue2);
      editor.commit();;
    }


}
```

Comment: Update to my answer available

Answer (score 0):

```
public class settup extends Activity {
 private String SENDER_ID = "xxx";
 private String PUSHBOT_ID = "xxx";
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "BuyMeCheckBoxes";

final CheckBox auto = null;
     final CheckBox imobiliare = null;


@Override
protected void onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(savedInstanceState);

     auto = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
     imobiliare = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);


    if (auto.isChecked()) {
        auto.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(settup.this, 
                "1111111", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }

    if (imobiliare.isChecked()) {
        auto.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(settup.this, 
                "2222222", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }






  // Array of choices
//      String colors[] = {"Toata Tara","Oradea","Timisoara","Bucuresti","Cluj-Napoca","Constanta","Iasi","Suceava","Targu Mures"};

    // Selection of the spinner


    // Application of the Array to the Spinner
//      ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, colors);
//      spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
//      spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);




}


protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 


      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

     boolean c1 = settings.getBoolean("auto", false);
    boolean c2 = settings.getBoolean("imobiliare", false);

    auto.setChecked(c1);
    imobiliare.setChecked(c2);

} 


@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

  boolean checkBoxValue1 = auto.isChecked();
  boolean checkBoxValue2 = imobiliare.isChecked();  

  editor.putBoolean("auto", checkBoxValue1);
  editor.putBoolean("imobiliare", checkBoxValue2);
  editor.commit();;
}
```

}

Comment: you need to declare the checkboxes as class fields, inside the class yet outside of all methods.  then, in onCreateView, set them equal to the findViewByID stuff, and also setOnClickListeners to them in that onCreateView method.  i updated my answer to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an OnClickListener, so for your case it should be something like this

----------------------------UPDATE-------------------------

```
//ensure activity implements on click listener
public class settup extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {



//set listener - put in onCreate method
auto.setOnClickListner(this);



//set up logic - also goes in onCreate method
auto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            final boolean isChecked = image.isChecked();
            switch (arg0.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkBox1:
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "1111111", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
```

Happy coding! :D